# Places autocomplete widget : bounds bias seems too weak

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want the Places autocomplete Widget to suggest places within France, but not restricted to France. I followed the [official guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/places-widget#Autocomplete.setBounds) and added bounds (I set a rectangle bound that does not overflow outside of France), but the places returned for the first digits chars are most of the time out of the bounds.

I saw in the reference that the bound is biased and not restricted to the bound, but the bias seems too weak. Is there any way to make it stronger? (a parameter ?)

Example : https://codepen.io/benjamin-chevillon/pen/XBrNLZ :

```
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputBounded, {
    types: ["geocode"],
    bounds: autocompleteBounds
});
```

When I type "33"  for example, 4 of the 5 suggestions are out of the bounds. Whereas the widget restricted to France returns a lot of places with '33'.

On the [official Google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete), the autocomplete bounds is linked to the map. By default, the map is centered on Sydney. If you type "33" you'll get Australia's places. But if you move to France you will get European suggestions (but outside of France). I saw that it happens only when we start typing number. But it is a common way in France to describe a postal address.

I created an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111234226, but they redirected me on SO.

Comment: Well I think you answered your own question. Results are either biased, or they are restricted to some area, country, etc. You filed your issue as a bug. I believe it should have been a feature request if you expected Google to add more flexibility. That said, searching for a number is a bit vague. If I just type "rue" (street) then all results are in France... Now why addresses out of France with "33" seem to have more weight than others... I can't answer that.

Comment: That said, you could build your own autocomplete widget by using the [Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/places-widget#AutocompleteService) which gives you full flexibility on how you display the results. You could for example mix 2 requests, 1 with a country restriction, 1 without (or with other arguments) and somehow merge results from the 2 requests (or display them separately... whatever works for you).

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/places-widget#AutocompleteService) for an example on how to use the service... if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried `strictBounds` parameter as suggested in issue tracker you refer to?

Answer (score -1):

In order to restrict results of autocomplete widget to your bounds you have to use `strictBounds` parameter that was mentioned in issue tracker:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions.strictBounds

> **strictBounds** - A boolean value, indicating that the Autocomplete widget should only return those places that are inside the bounds of the Autocomplete widget at the time the query is sent. Setting strictBounds to false (which is the default) will make the results biased towards, but not restricted to, places contained within the bounds.

So, your code should be rewritten as

```
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputBounded, {
    types: ["geocode"],
    bounds: autocompleteBounds,
    strictBounds: true
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: *I want the Places autocomplete Widget to suggest places within France, but not restricted to France.*